# Harvest (rvest) multiple HTML pages from a list of urls

Tags: r, rvest

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
country <- c("Canada", "US", "Japan", "China")
url <- c("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada",
          "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China")
df <- data.frame(country, url)

    country link
1   Canada  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States
2   US      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada
3   Japan   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan
4   China   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China
```

Using `rvest` I'd like to scrape the *table of contents* for each url and bind them to one single output.

This code extracts the table of contents for one url:

```
library(rvest)
toc <- html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".toctext") %>%
  html_text()
```

Desired Output:

```
country toc
US      Etymology
        History
        Native American and European contact
        Settlements
        ...  
Canada  Etymology
        History
        Aboriginal peoples
        European colonization
        ...etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will scrape them into a full data frame (one row per TOC entry). Tedious-but-straightforward "print/output" code left to the OP:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

country <- c("Canada", "US", "Japan", "China")
url <- c("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States", 
         "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada",
         "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan", 
         "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China")
df <- data.frame(country, url)

bind_rows(lapply(url, function(x) {

  data.frame(url=x, toc_entry=toc <- html(url[1]) %>%
    html_nodes(".toctext") %>%
    html_text())

})) -> toc_entries

df <- toc_entries %>% left_join(df)

df[sample(nrow(df), 10),]

## Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
## 
##                                           url                            toc_entry country
## 1          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan                   Government finance   Japan
## 2         http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada        Cold War and civil rights era      US
## 3  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States                                 Food  Canada
## 4          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan                               Sports   Japan
## 5         http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada                             Religion      US
## 6          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China        Cold War and civil rights era   China
## 7          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan Literature, philosophy, and the arts   Japan
## 8  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States                           Population  Canada
## 9          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan                          Settlements   Japan
## 10        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada                             Military      US
```