# lapply, difference between c() and list()

Tags: r, rvest

What is the difference between c() and list()? 
I'm learning some webscraping and ran into an unexpected error. 
I wrote a small script to scrape baseball data from a few pages on ESPN's website:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

Baseball <- read_html("http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/batting/_/qualified/true")
Baseball.2 <- read_html("http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/batting/_/count/41/qualified/true")
Baseball.3 <- read_html("http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/batting/_/count/81/qualified/true")
Baseball.4 <- read_html("http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/batting/_/count/121/qualified/true")
Baseball.list <- c(Baseball, Baseball.2, Baseball.3, Baseball.4)


scrape <- function(html) {
  temp.df <- data.frame(1:length(html %>%
                                   html_nodes(paste0("td:nth-child(2)")) %>%
                                   html_text()))
  for (i in 2:19) {
  temp.df[i - 1] <- 
    html %>%
    html_nodes(paste0("td:nth-child(", i, ")")) %>%
    html_text()
  }
  temp.df
}
```

when I run `df <- lapply(Baseball.list, scrape)` I get:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "externalptr"
```

But, if I run `Baseball.list <- list(Baseball, Baseball.2, Baseball.3, Baseball.4)` and then use lapply and my function in the exact same way it works without a problem! I checked the documentation for `c()` and see that:
 "This is a generic function which combines its arguments.
The default method combines its arguments to form a vector. All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value, and all attributes except names are removed," whereas the documentation for `list()`says its coerces objects into a list. Can someone explain why using `c()` in this instance causes lapply to fail? I'm not understanding the documentation.

Comment: The first `Baseball.list` (with `c()`) is coerced to `as.list(Baseball.list)` in `lapply`, so compare that to your second `Baseball.list`.

Comment: I see the difference in output, but still don't fully understand the implications of the output. Part of my confusion is that in other answers (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906601/harvest-rvest-multiple-html-pages-from-a-list-of-urls?rq=1) they seem to be doing something similar but c() works fine. Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as the documentation for `c()` says,

> "All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value, and all attributes except names are removed"

The list keeps the classes of the documents as was intended by `xml2::read_html`. If you look at the [source code for xml2](https://github.com/hadley/xml2/blob/a3afb411f4c13893acf7608a1f88c1f996123bec/R/xml_find.R) , you'll see that the generic method `xml_find_all` is only defined for classes of `xml_missing`, `xml_node` and `xml_nodeset`

```
> class(read_html("<html><title>Hi<title></html>"))
[1] "xml_document" "xml_node"    
> a = read_html("<html><title>Hi<title></html>")
> b = read_html("<html><title>Hi<title></html>")
> c = read_html("<html><title>Hi<title></html>")
> lapply(c(a,b,c), class)
$node
[1] "externalptr"

$doc
[1] "externalptr"

$node
[1] "externalptr"

$doc
[1] "externalptr"

$node
[1] "externalptr"

$doc
[1] "externalptr"

> lapply(list(a,b,c), class)
[[1]]
[1] "xml_document" "xml_node"    

[[2]]
[1] "xml_document" "xml_node"    

[[3]]
[1] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```