# Scrape and Loop with Rvest

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rvest

I have reviewed several answers to similar questions on SO related to this similar topic but neither seem to work for me.

([loop across multiple urls in r with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666406/loop-across-multiple-urls-in-r-with-rvest))

([Harvest (rvest) multiple HTML pages from a list of urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906601/harvest-rvest-multiple-html-pages-from-a-list-of-urls))

I have a list of URLs and I wish to grab the table from each and append it to a master dataframe.

```
## get all urls into one list
page<- (0:2)
urls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(page)) {
  url<- paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/stats/season?page=",page[i])
  urls[[i]] <- url
}


### loop over the urls and get the table from each page
table<- data.frame()
for (j in urls) {
  tbl<- urls[j] %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node("table") %>%
    html_table()
  table[[j]] <- tbl
}
```

The first section works as expect  and gets the list of urls I want to scrape.  I get the following error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Any suggestions on how to get correct for this error and get the 3 tables looped into a single DF?  I appreciate any tips or pointers.

Comment: Have you tried assigning `j <- 1` outside the for loop then `j <- j+1` inside your for loop after `table[[j]] <- tbl` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

page<- (0:2)
urls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(page)) {
  url<- paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/stats/season?page=",page[i])
  urls[[i]] <- url
}

### loop over the urls and get the table from each page
tbl <- list()
j <- 1
for (j in seq_along(urls)) {
  tbl[[j]] <- urls[[j]] %>%   # tbl[[j]] assigns each table from your urls as an element in the tbl list
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node("table") %>%
    html_table()
  j <- j+1                    # j <- j+1 iterates over each url in turn and assigns the table from the second url as an element of tbl list, [[2]] in this case
}

#convert list to data frame
tbl <- do.call(rbind, tbl)
```

`table[[j]] <- tbl` at the end of your for loop in the original code was not necessary as we're assigning each url as an element of the `tbl` list here: `tbl[[j]] <- urls[[j]]`

Comment: Thanks @on_an_island.  Exactly the output I was looking for.

Comment: i know is not the best way ask here, but, how could i add a column to the table, showing what "j" was used? (i'm adapting the solution)

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula just add `tbl[[j]]$j <- j` directly before `j <- j+1`. This will append a column with the `j`th value. Or you could mutate the column by replacing `html_table()` with `html_table() %>% mutate(j = j)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

```
for (j in urls) {
  tbl<- urls[j] %>%
```

When you use `j in urls` the `j` values are not integers, they are the urls themselves.

Try:

```
for (j in 1:length(urls)) {
  tbl<- urls[[j]] %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node("table") %>%
    html_table()
  table[[j]] <- tbl
}
```

You can also use `seq_along()`:

```
for (j in seq_along(urls))
```

Comment: that seems to fix the original issue, however it creates a new error which I don't understand. " Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*, j, value = list(list(Player = c("Diego Rubio", : replacement has 1 row, data has 0 " – Brad_J 25 mins ago