# Simple solution to scrape and loop with rvest, storing the results of the for-loop in a variable

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rvest

I need to collect the links from 3 pages, each having 150 links, using R with rvest library. I used a for-loop to crawl through the pages. I know that it's a very basic question, which has been answered elsewhere:
[R web scraping across multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683510/r-web-scraping-across-multiple-pages)
[Scrape and Loop with Rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679009/scrape-and-loop-with-rvest)
I tried different versions of the following code. Most of them worked but returned only 50 instead of 150 links

```
library(rvest)

baseurl <- "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=chain+and+sprocket&_sacat=0&_pgn="
n <- 1:3
nextpages <- paste0(baseurl, n)

for(i in nextpages){
  html <- read_html(nextpages)
  links <- html %>% html_nodes("a.vip") %>% html_attr("href")
}
```

The code is expected to return all the 150, instead of just 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the links variable in every iteration, so you would only end up with the last 50 links.

But you're looping using the 'i' variable, whereas your read_html() function uses the nextpages variable, which is actually a vector of 3 urls. You should be getting an error.

Try this:

```
links <- c()
for(i in nextpages){
  html <- read_html(i)
  links <- c(links, html %>% html_nodes("a.vip") %>% html_attr("href"))
}
```

Comment: How can we do this with a data.frame() and rbind(), instead of c()?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map` instead of a `for` loop.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

map(nextpages, . %>% read_html %>%
               html_nodes("a.vip") %>% 
               html_attr("href")) %>% flatten_chr()

#[1] "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Genuine-Honda-Chain-and-sprocket-set-Honda-Cub-C50-C70-C90-Heavy-Duty/254287014069?hash=item3b34afe8b5:g:wjEAAOSwqaBdH69W"         
#[2] "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DID-Heavy-Duty-Drive-Chain-And-JT-Sprocket-Kit-For-Honda-MSX125-Grom-2013-2019/223130604262?hash=item33f39ed2e6:g:QmwAAOSwdrpcAQ4c"
#.....
#...
```

Comment: Nice. +  So, looking up flatten_chr in https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/flatten.html  seems if you had 3 levels deep you end up at two and if at two you end up at one and so on?  How were you using it here?

Comment: @QHarr `map` is like `lapply` it returns list, by using `flatten_chr` we make it into character vector. See the difference between output of `lapply(1:10, sqrt)` and `lapply(1:10, sqrt) %>% flatten_dbl()`